# Ms Access VBA - Trying to call data from a combo box but only if a field is empty

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

From the code below I want [KronosNO] to come from a database Combo box
but only if the [RTWDate] column is Null.

```
Set Rs = Application.CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(
  "SELECT * FROM tblAbsence WHERE [KronosNo] = '" & Me.cmbKronosNo.Value & "' 
   AND [RTWDate] = '" & "Is Null" & "' ", dbOpenDynaset)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't treat `Is Null` like a variable, it is a part of SQL.

You simply need

```sql
AND [RTWDate] Is Null
```

in your string.